# Making Email Delivery delay

Tags: php, html, web-services

This is some type of funny question to ask here.

Well, I am using WordPress with registration. When a user signup. Wordpress send email containing user name and password to login.

I simply want that email to receive after delay of 10 minutes. Is there is something to do with server config OR with WP.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you checked your **sendmail** configuration? and the refer the following link that might help you, http://collinhenderson.com/post/48046976172/a-fix-for-slow-sendmail-on-ubuntu[link]

Comment: Does wordpress using 3rd party libraries such swiftmailer or phpmailer?

Answer (score -1):

You would have to have multiple things to have it work, you will need to have access to cron in order to delay the job and you need to be able have enough knowledge to edit WordPress to stop the function from sending the email. If you can schedule the job to run a command with the parameters for the email in it 10 minutes later the rest should run on its own.

Comment: I thought there should be a quick way to do it!

Comment: Unless you can find a plugin, this is the best way

Comment: Well then you have your solution.